# <label for><input /><label> - focus immediately lost

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, focus

I have a radio-button group with radio buttons and associated labels with `for` attributes and one of the labels contain a text-box.
I now have the problem, that as soon as I click the textbox the focus is removed again.
See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3KzFK/) - try selecting the text box to enter something.

I already tryed the following in the `onclick` or `onfocus`:

```
setInterval(function () { $('#TriggerTimeUI').focus(); }, 50)
```

This seems to work, but I have a `datetimepicker` on that control and that is "killing" this logic as it is then shown all the time (see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RWtd7/1/), but this fiddle only works in Chrome)...

**Can someone help me with this?**

Comment: Why do you have a text box inside the label for a different element? Clicking on a label causes focus to be set to the `for` element.

Comment: The textbox is inside a label with "for" attribute. It makes the element with the id "TriggerMode_custom" to focus and first id in the document will be taken into account and so radio button is focussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have the `for` attribute of the label set to a sibling element. This means that a click event will be raised on the element named in the attribute, hence why focus is immediately lost from the textbox. Remove the `for` attribute and the textbox keeps focus:

```
<input type="radio" name="TriggerMode" id="TriggerMode_custom" value="custom" checked="checked" />
<label> <!-- remove the 'for' here -->
    <input style="width: 230px;" type="Text" id="TriggerTimeUI" />
    <br />
</label>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3KzFK/1/)

If you need that behaviour that when someone clicks into the text box the radio button is selected, you will need to do that manually:

```
$('#TriggerTimeUI').focus(function() {
    $('#TriggerMode_custom').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Another example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3KzFK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped your input text box under label tag which belongs to radio button. Just end the label tag where it starts like below and your problem will go

```
<label for="TriggerMode_custom"></label>
        <input style="width: 230px;" type="Text" id="TriggerTimeUI" /><br />
```